# Shift Rows Containing Data to the Top

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I wonder whether someone could possibly help me please.

So that I can maintain a given 'Input Range' I'm trying to put together a script which removes cell content from user selected row or rows. Then move all rows with data to the top of my spreadsheet if column "A" starting from row 7 is populated.

I've put together the code below which removes the cell content from the row, but I can't work out how to move the 'Shift Up' the rows containing data to sit one under another, omitting any blank rows between the data.

```
Sub DelRow()
    Dim msg

        Sheets("Input").Protect "password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
        Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        msg = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", vbYesNo)
        If msg = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        With Selection
            Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:R"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("S:AD"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("AF:AQ"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I've put together a 'Sort' macro shown below, and although this works with two consecutive rows containing data, it does not work for rows that I have used my 'Delete' macro on.

For example, if I populate the first and second row of my 'Input Range', the code correctly sorts the spreadsheet using column "B" as the sort criteria. But if I remove the content of the first row, hence creating a blank row, the 'Sort' script does not shift up the second row.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    With Sheets("Input")
        If .Range("A7").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        .Range("B7:AS400").Sort Key1:=Range("$B$1"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DatOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
End Sub
```

I just wondered whether someone could possibly take a look at this please and offer some guidance on how I need to adapt my code so that I can add the sort functionality.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: After answering your question and then re-reading your question... are you actually trying to delete the entire row, or just part of it?

Comment: Hi @Daniel Cook, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I'm not deleting the rows because I need the 'Input Range' to remain unchnaged, so I'm removing the cell content instead. Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following more searching on the internet, I found the following article:
http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=178521

Using this, I've amended my 'Delete Row' code to the following which works perfectly:

```
Sub DelRow()
    Dim msg

        Sheets("Input").Protect "handsoff", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
        Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        msg = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", vbYesNo)
        If msg = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        With Selection
            Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:R"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("S:AD"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("AF:AQ"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        End With
       Application.EnableEvents = True
            With Range("A7:AS400" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            .Sort Key1:=Range("B7"), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlNo, _
            OrderCustom:=1, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you very much to all who have been kind enough to offer help.

Many thanks and a very happy New Year.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

To delete the row based upon your code, your best option is this:

`Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp`

If you want to make sure the entire row is deleted then you want this:

`Selection.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp`

As for sorting afterwards, if that is necessary you should look into [Range.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx)

---

Edit: If you want to remove part of the row, yet be specific you can do something like this:

`Range(Cells(Selection.Row,5),Cells(Selection.Row,8)).Delete Shift:=xlUp` This would apply the delete to columns `E-H`.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Cook, as per my answer from your original comment. I'm not wanting to delete the row because I need to maintain a fixed 'Input Range'. Unless there is another way of doing so, which I'm more than happy to be shown, the only I knew to achieve this was to clear the cell content. But I would then like, if at all possible please for any rows which contain datato be moved to the top so that there are no blank rows between those that conatin data. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Cook, thank you very much for coming back to me on this. I've put together a 'Sort' script which I've now included in my original post. If I add two consecutive rows containing data, the sort correctly works using column "B" as the sort criteria. However if I use my 'Delete' macro as shown initially, the contents of the cell are correctly removed, hence creating a blank row, but the sort function does not move the second row up, thus removing the blank row. I hope this helps. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi @Daniel Cook, please see the answer I've posted. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Header to xlNo instead of xlGuess. Excel may "think" that you have a header row which it will not include in the rows to be sorted, so your blank top row will stay there.

That is, change 
`Header:=xlGuess` to `Header:=xlNo`

Comment: Hi @Lord Peter, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. Please see the ansewer I've posted. Kind regards